# When in the Mongodb shell, how to run cls and a mongodb shell command on one line?

Tags: mongodb, shell

When in the Mongodb shell, I can run:

```
cls <enter>
db.test.find() <enter>
```

on two seperate lines to clear the screen and then see the result from the find().

Is there a way to do this on one line?  I tried:

```
cls; db.test.find() <enter>
cls & db.test.find() <enter>
(cls); db.test.find() <enter>
```

None of these work.

Comment: It's a REPL and not really a "shell" in the "bash" sense. It only essentially evaluates one expression at a time. If you are looking to "program" things, then use a programming language. The mongo shell was never intended to provide such an environment and is merely a "tool" to do "quick and dirty" things. Also `cls` is not an "expression". It's just a "built in", just like `use`.

Comment: @Neil Lunn cls (clearing the screen) and performing one command to find some records is a quick and dirty thing and no attempt to program.  Just want to clear the screen each time without having to type cls, hit enter, then type the command and hit enter again.  Especially when only changing one value in the find().  Up arrow brings up the previous command, change a value, hit enter.... and want to clear the screen and show the result.

Comment: Somehow I'm not clear enough. You cannot do that. You can do `print("\033c"); db.test.find()` sending the character code to clear a screen, but since `cls` is not actually implemented as a JavaScript expression like the `db.collection.find()` is then you simply cannot type a semi-colon after it. So there it is, but it would seemingly defeat the purpose. Live without clearing the screen, or use a different tool.

Comment: I suppose you could just define a short function i.e `c = () => print("\033c")` and then you can do `c(); db.test.find()`. That's three keystrokes once you have it, albeit with holding shift down for two of them.

Comment: If you're on windows then it believe it's a different control sequence. That's the char code for *nix based terminals

Comment: @Neil Lunn Same code.   Doesn't work in the mongodb shell. However, print("\n".repeat(50)); does work. Which effectively clears the screen and is a big help.  Post it as the answer and I will accept.

Comment: Works fine in the shell for me on any *nix based system. It has to since it the "standard" control sequence for ANSI terminals (which is why I know it). Windows is "non compliant" to say the least. At any rate, if you "are" on windows, then simply press `<ctrl>+L`. That's always been a way to clear screen in a Win32 console. A lot more convenient to type. The basic control sequences and keys question has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow already. It's not the "mongo shell", but the basic command environment.

Comment: @Neil Lunn It is mongo shell running in Windows.  Ctrl-L does work. But the print(); idea is better.  Type it one time along with the find() command, hit enter, then up arrow to bring up the line with the print and find() command, change the criteria, and hit enter.  Repeat with up arrow several times.  No need to even hit ctrl-L.  Easy to use... used it already several times just now.  Thanks again.